# Serializing an image in a dataTable with datacontractjsonserializer

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am serializing an DataTable with datacontractjsonserializer and passing it as JSON in C#. The problem im having is all the fields gets serialized as strings. FirstName and LastName is correct but the Picture field get serialized as

> "System.Byte[]" string and not an object.

Please advise how do I serialize it as an object an pass it via JSON ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/converting-images-to-json-objects/

Comment: Great. Added the link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.Net library handles the byte conversion. please refer [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Can you please provide a C# example. I am unable to get the classes and name space for this. final and ByteArrayOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

covert your byte image to string like this

```
string result=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Your_Image);
```

then append the result to your fields. 
In the other side do this
split your fields to get your fields by a splitter
then you can get your image like this

```
byte[]your_image= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Result_After_splitting) ;
```

Hope it helps